# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException occurred and return null

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I just make a mail class refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/7354469)

and `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` occurred with return null.

> 11-26 22:51:25.053 19008-20169/com.example.android.mailGenerater E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
>                                                                                Process: com.example.android.mailGenerater, PID: 19008
>                                                                                javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
>                                                                                    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
>                                                                                    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
>                                                                                    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
>                                                                                    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
>                                                                                    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
>                                                                                    at com.example.android.mailGenerater.SendGmailManager(SendGmailManager.kt:145)
>                                                                                    at com.example.android.mailGenerater.MyActivity$onCreate$1$1.run(MyActivity.kt:60)

I used `exception` code with it

```
 catch (e: AuthenticationFailedException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "auth failed : ${e.localizedMessage}") // print : "auth failed : null"
        e.printStackTrace() // not working.
```

It show nothing.

that exception return null, so print stack trace not working.

---

I want to know ***when AuthenticationFailedException occurred with null***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry

this problem rely on all my mistake.

I miss bellow code at child class of `javax.mail.Authenticator`

```
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}
```

I think `Null occurred` when if there is no `override method : getPasswordAuthentication()`

when i add override method, it work very well.

Comment: Note that you probably [don't even need to use an Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) at all.